# PowerBI filters not affecting table constructed in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, power-bi-report-server

I have run into a challenge in PowerBI and describe it below using generic non-sensitive data.

My report is based on a single data table "DummyTable" consisting of a workDate, billCode and locationCode (strings) and duration (integer).

I need to present some summarised details for DummyTable and thought it would be clever to use the DAX table constuctor to produce a small table summarising our key statistics using the CALCULATE function. This seemed to work well enough.

```
ConstructedTable = 
    VAR CountAllWork =  CALCULATE(COUNT(DummyTable[BillCode]),
                            ALL(DummyTable)
                        )
    VAR CountRareGoods = CALCULATE(COUNT(DummyTable[BillCode]),
                            KEEPFILTERS(
                                DummyTable[BillCode] IN{"RareGoods"}
                            )
                         )
    VAR CountBulks =    CALCULATE(COUNT(DummyTable[BillCode]),
                            KEEPFILTERS(
                                DummyTable[BillCode] IN{"Something","Else","Flanges","Tails"}
                            )
                        )
    VAR CountSpecials = CALCULATE(COUNT(DummyTable[BillCode]),
                            KEEPFILTERS(
                                DummyTable[BillCode] IN{"Something","Else","Flanges","Tails"} &&
                                DummyTable[Duration] > 80
                            )
                        )
RETURN
{ --Index, Title, Value
    (01,"Count of all work",CountAllWork),
    (02,"Count of rare goods",CountRareGoods),
    (03,"Count of bulk bills",CountBulks),
    (04,"Count of special cases",CountSpecials)
}
```

This neatly presents the required summary data in a small table.

[image: yes_a_table]

However when I try to apply external filters against this table (either using the filter pane or slicers) they have no effect. For instance a slicer referring to DummyTable[LocationCode] lists all the location codes but no matter what is chosen, the constructed table remains unchanged. I have used KEEPFILTERS which I thought would have worked with this.

[image: filters_why_you_no_work]

I cannot create a relationship between the constructed table ("ConstructedTable") and the original data table ("Dummy") because the constucted table contains only summary data; there is nothing to build a relationship on.

I am assuming (hoping) there is something simple wrong with the DAX code used to construct the table and a revision will solve the issue.

(Alternately, if you think my approach using a table consturctor is entirely wrong please let me know also...)

Many thanks

Comment: Your approach is entirely wrong. Calculated tables and calculated columns are always static. It does not matter that you used DAX formulas to construct them - after the calculations are done, the results are stored as data, not as formulas. The calculated data is identical to the imported data. Static data, naturally, can't respond to slicers - only DAX measures can.

Comment: Thanks @RADO, I was really expecting someone to say my approach is wrong... I now understand that calculated tables are entirely static. Makes sense. Thanks again.